# How should I understand this sentence from Knausgaard's My Struggle?

Tags: commas, clauses

> If we lay close together our physical range was not much to brag about
> either, any given sea lion would be more voluminous.

Could anyone explain the comma usage in this sentence? Is there should be a comma before "our?"
It seems to me there are two main clauses here("our physical ... either" and "any ... voluminous.")

Comment: Yes, there are. I would have used a semicolon or a dash between them.

Comment: I think there's something "lost in translation" here. Most likely Knausgaard intended some allusion to the ***amount of bodily contact*** between two people (or sea lions) when "snuggling up". But "voluminous" doesn't really mean that. It means "having great volume or bulk" - usually applied to "puffed up, billowing" loose clothing; not really connected to the idea of ***maximised skin-to-skin contact***.